# Webview Zoom in out function

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have task regarding on zoom in and out function for webview. i have two buttons in and out .i want to give the zoom when clik action is done on buttons only. but i got default zoom function 
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

What should i do for getting zoom while click on those two buttons..

Answer (score 0):

you may need to subclass the webview and override the onTouchEvent and ignore the touches you don't want to process

Comment: If i ignore the touch , how i can give Zoom action for both buttons..,Which function it supports.

Answer (score 0):

```
wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); or false
```

hope this helps